# Count by styles instead of colors

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
'SELECT count(`houses`.`color`) AS `count`, 
        `houses`.`color` 
FROM    `user_houses` 
JOIN    `houses` ON `houses`.`id` = `users_houses`.`house` 
GROUP BY `houses`.`color`'
```

This is the statement I use to count houses by color property (in houses table).

Every house has an style name. I need to count the different styles, instead of the different colors. The problem is the style is in another table (styles) which has a house_id that maches the house_id from houses.

I have tried this:

```
'JOIN houses AND styles SELECT count(`style`.`color`) AS `count`, `houses`.`style` FROM `user_houses` 'JOIN `houses` ON `houses`.`id` = `user_houses`.`house` GROUP BY `houses`.`color`'
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff uh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given limited info : You need to join houses with styles.
Even your mentioned query has an unnecessary join over user_houses. Try this :

```
SELECT count(`styles`.`house_id`) AS `count`, 
        `styles`.`house_id` 
FROM    `houses`
INNER JOIN    `styles` ON `houses`.`house_id` = `styles`.`house_id` 
GROUP BY `styles`.`house_id`
```

Comment: I had two replace one or two words but after that it worked. Thanks, man.